# Loop thru a directory and search in all pre-filtered XML files for a word

Tags: python, syntax, indentation

I would like to loop through a given directory and seach in all pre-filtered files
for a search word. I prepared this code, but it is not looping thru all files, only
the last file which was found is analyzed. Ideally all files should be analyzed and
the output should be saved in a textfile. Could someone help?

```
import os, glob

for filename in glob.glob("C:\\test*.xml"):
    print filename

for line in open(filename):
    if "SEARCHWORD" in line:
        print line
```

**The OUTPUT is looking like:**

```
C:\test-261.xml
C:\test-262.xml
C:\test-263.xml
C:\test-264.xml
<Area>SEARCHWORD</Area>
```

Comment: You know, indentation is meaningful in python...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use the codify button above the edit field to format code sample properly. Ans please (this one is my personal opinion) refrain from using words like *thru* when *through* is so close.

Answer (score 2):

Indent the 2nd `for`-loop one more level to make it loop for every file found.

```
for filename in glob.glob("C:\\test*.xml"):
    print filename

#-->
    for line in open(filename):
        if "SEARCHWORD" in line:
            print line
```

BTW, since you are just iterating on the globbed result instead of storing it, [you should use `glob.iglob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to save for duplicating the list. Also, it is better to put that `open()` in a [`with`-statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) so that the file can be closed properly even an exception is thrown.

```
for filename in glob.iglob('C:\\test*.xml'):
   print filename
   with open(filename) as f:
      for line in f:
         if 'SEARCHWORD' in line:
            print line
```

Comment: Cool, thank you for helping ! Thats it! Now I just have to save the output into a textfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the results in a file:

```
import os, glob
results = open('results.txt', 'w')
for filename in glob.glob("C:\test*.xml"):
    for line in open(filename):
        if "SEARCHWORD" in line:
            results.write(line)
results.close()
```